# Changing the value of a int variable through pointers passed as arguments?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to modify values of some variables of a particular class by accessing address of these variables from another different class through a function. So, to access this address I try to pass pointers-to-variables as arguments to a function, where these pointers-to-variables will be set with the address of the variables. To learn how to do it, I'm trying to mimic in a simple program.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;
int numberA = 100;
int numberB = 200;

void referenceSetter(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a = numberA;
    *b = numberB;
}

void numberOutput()
{
    cout << "A = " << numberA << endl;
    cout << "B = " << numberB << endl;
}

int main() {

    int *testA = 0; 
    int *testB = 0;
    referenceSetter(testA, testB);

    *testA = 30;
    *testB = 40;
    numberOutput();

    return 0;
}
```

As you could see I declare `numberA` and `numberB` as global variables and set their values. The I try to get the address of these two variables through the function `referenceSetter` function and then after that I try to modify the values in those variables using the references. Apparently, I'm doing something wrong which leads to to have `Unhandled Exception` error exactly when I try to modify the values and try to set them as 30 and 40 resepectively.

Alternatively I tried the following approach:

```
#include <iostream>    

    using namespace std;
    int numberA = 100;
    int numberB = 200;

    void referenceSetter(int *a, int *b)
    {
        a = &numberA;
        b = &numberB;
    }

    void numberOutput()
    {
        cout << "A = " << numberA << endl;
        cout << "B = " << numberB << endl;
    }

    int main() {

        int *testA; 
        int *testB;
        referenceSetter(testA, testB);

        *testA = 30;
        *testB = 40;
        numberOutput();

        return 0;
    }
```

But this approach throws up the error `uninitialized local variables testA and testB`. Do I have to initialize pointers too?

Please help me find my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger to find where the exception occurs, and the state of the program when that happens?  That'd be the first step.

Comment: Wait, it crashes when you try to assign the value 30 to `*testA`?  Interesting, I could have sworn it should have crashed before that.  Maybe the optimizer did something wonky that bypassed the error I saw.

Comment: **C is not C++ is not C!** Do not add C-tag for C++ code!

Comment: @Olaf Is pointer not part of c too?

Comment: And `if` is part of Python, Java, Basic, etc. Do you want to add these taggs, too? You have C++ code and a C++ question, so do not use the C tag. These are different languages!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you're not understanding is that pointers are passed by value, just like any other variable.  If you want the passed pointer to be changed, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer (or a reference to a pointer, but I'll leave that alone, as explaining references at this point will confuse you further).

Your `main()` is passing NULL pointers to `referenceSetter()`.   The assignment `*a = numberA` copies the value of `numberA` (i.e. `100`) into the memory pointed to by `a`.  Since `a` is a NULL pointer, that has the effect of overwriting memory that doesn't exist as far as your program is concerned.   The result of that is undefined behaviour which means - according to the standard - that anything is allowed to happen.   With your implementation, that is triggering an unhandled exception, probably because your host operating system is detecting that your program is writing to memory that it is not permitted to write to.

If, after the call of `referenceSetter()` you want `testA` and `testB` to contain the addresses of `numberA` and `numberB` respectively, you need to change `referenceSetter()` to something like;

```
void referenceSetter(int **a, int **b)
{
    *a = &numberA;
    *b = &numberB;
}
```

This allows the values passed to be addresses of pointers.  `*a` then becomes a reference to the pointer passed.    `&numberA` compute the address of `numberA`, rather than accessing its value `100`.   Similarly for `numberB`.

The second change is to change `main()` so it calls the function correctly;

```
referenceSetter(&testA, &testB);
```

which passes the address of `testA` (and `testB`) to the function, so those pointers can be changed

Comment: Thanks! This was a very good answer, it helped me understand clearly and now I have solved it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set the contents of address `0` to be equal to the other numbers, so when you're doing `*a = numberA` you're assigning a value of `numberA` to memory address `0`.

Not sure, but I think what you're trying to achieve is this:

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;
int numberA = 100;
int numberB = 200;

void referenceSetter(int **a, int **b)
{
    *a = &numberA;
    *b = &numberB;
}

void numberOutput()
{
    cout << "A = " << numberA << endl;
    cout << "B = " << numberB << endl;
}

int main() {

    int *testA = 0;
    int *testB = 0;
    referenceSetter(&testA, &testB);
    *testA = 30;
    *testB = 40;
    numberOutput();
    return 0;
}
```

This way, using pointers to pointers as arguments for `referenceSetter()`, you are actually modifying the address that your passed pointers are pointing to.

Comment: You are passing `testA` and `testB` by value so no change will take effect because you're modifying the copied pointers inside the function, not the actual pointers you pass to it. You need pointers to pointers as I note in my code. Please test it.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. :) I learned something new, I never used pointers to pointers so explicit as I did today.

Comment: Congrats! I also had a bad time understanding all of this.

Answer (score -1):

You are close, but the key is you need to pass the **address of** the value you want to set. You declare the values as `int` in `main` and pass the address by using the `&` operator:

```
int *testA = 0;
int *testB = 0;
referenceSetter(&testA, &testB);

*testA = 30;
*testB = 40;
numberOutput();
```

If you declare `testA` and `testB` as pointers in `main` and pass the pointer, the function gets **a copy of the pointer** instead of the **address of the value** you want to set.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this approach, but this doesn't change the value of numberA and numberB when I set the new values of testA and testB. I would like to modify numberA and numberB through using their address. Is there any I can do so?

Comment: Well, yes, it is the exact same thing, you just need one additional level of indirection.  alsegdia has already provided that answer.